# When did Vishnu destroy trident of Shiva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, weapon, padma-purana, vishnu-sahasranama

Vishnu Sahasranama stotram consist of thousand names of Lord Vishnu. The most popular one is from Anushasana parva of Mahabharata which was said by Bhishma to Yudhishtira. But there are other versions of Vishnu Sahasranamam i.e., there are other names of Lord Vishnu in other puranas. They occur in Skanda Purana, Padma Purana and Garuda Purana where the reciter and listener are different.

Vishnu Sahasranama stotram from the Padma Purana is present in the Uttara Khanda. Lord Shiva says these names to Parvati. Following is an excerpt of the stotra

> **shivatrishoolavidhvamsee** shreekanThaikavarapradah |
>   narahkrushNo haridharmanandano dharmajeevanah || 52
>    ||
>
> **He is the destroyer of Siva's trident**.He is the only giver of
>   boons to Siva. He is the 'man'. He is Krsna. He is Hari. He is
>   delighted in righteousness. Righteousness is his life.

When did Lord Vishnu destroy the trident of Lord Shiva?

Comment: The Shanti Parva describes the fight between Narayana Rishi and Rudra, where he destroys the "lance" of Rudra. Have to check whether Shula is translated as lance. If so it would make sense, since the next line talks about Narayana Rishi's brothers Nara, Hari and Krsna - Dharmananandanah could be a special reference to Narayana, or a description of Hari.

Answer (score 5):

The verse quoted from Padma Purana's Vishnu Sahasranama most probably refers to the battle between Narayana and Rudra described in [this chapter of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c042.htm). The Sanskrit verses for the same can be [referred here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-12-itx.html).

It is the 343rd chapter of Shanti Parva as per KMG's source recension, and the 352nd Chapter as per the Kumbhakonam recension of the Mahabharata. (The chapter number differences are more due to the difference in splitting up of chapters rather than additional chapters between recensions.)

In this chapter, while explaining some of his names to Arjuna, Lord Krsna talks about those names wherein he identifies himself with Lord Shiva (in the sense that Hari and Hara are the same entity who have taken two different forms). These names include Ishana, Munjakesha, Khandaparashu and others.

In this regard, Krsna mentions of a battle between Narayana, the son of Dharmadeva and twin brother of Nara, and Rudra, Lord Shiva in his fierce form as the destroyer of Daksha Yaaga.

In the due course of the destruction of Daksha's sacrifice, Rudra releases a Shula (lance) to destroy the beings who participated in the sacrifice. Having burnt the intended, the Shula proceeds towards Badarikashrama, where Nara and Narayana are performing penance.

> tachChUlaM bhasmasAtkR^itvA dakShayaj~naM savistaram.
> AvayoH sahasA.agachChadvadaryAshramamantikAt.
> vegena mahatA pArtha patannArAyaNorasi.. 12-352-44

> "That Shula, after destroying Daksha's Yajna, came towards us (Nara and Narayana), and with great force slammed on Narayana's chest."

> tattasyatejasA.a.aviShTAH keshA nArAyaNasya ha.
> babhUvurmu~njavarNAstu tato.ahaM **mu~njakeshavAn**.. 12-352-45
> tachcha **shUlaM vinirdhUtaM** huMkAreNa mahAtmanA.
> jagAma shaMkarakaraM **nArAyaNasamAhatam**.. 12-352-46

> "Affected by the energy of the Shula, the hair of Narayana turned the colour of Hay (Munja), by which I came to be called Munjakesha.  Narayana then let out a great Humkara by which the Shula was rendered effectless and returned to the hands of Shankara."

Following this a battle occurs between Narayana and Rudra wherein Narayana grabbed hold of Rudra's throat, causing it to change into a dark blue hue, following which he came to be called Shitikantha.

To prevent further destruction, Brahma requests Rudra to cease the fight and make peace with Narayana, who was after all engaged in penance and not fighting battles. Rudra does as Brahma requests him to, and Narayana becomes pleased with Lord Shiva and says how he and Shiva are the same reality in two different forms for the benefit of the world.

> brahmaNA tvevamuktastu rudraH krodhAgnimutsR^ijan.
> prasAdayAmAsa tato devaM nArAyaNaM prabhum.
> sharaNaM cha jagAmAdyaM vareNyaM **varadaM** harim.. 12-352-64

> "Upon hearing the words of Brahma, Rudra discarded his anger and pleased Narayana, the excellent one, the bestower of boons, the reliever of distress, and sought his refuge."

> tato.atha varado devo jitakrodho jitendriyaH.
> prItimAnabhavattatra rudreNa saha saMgataH.. 12-352-65
> R^iShibhirbrahmaNA chaiva vibudhaishcha supUjitaH.
> uvAcha devamIshAnamIshaH sa jagato hariH.. 12-352-66
> yastvAM vetti sa mAM vetti yastvAmanu sa mAmanu.
> nAvayorantaraM kiMchinmA te.abhUdvuddhiranyathA.. 12-352-67

> "Then the Lord Varada (bestower of boons), conquerer of anger and senses became pleased with Rudra and had a parlay. Being worshipped by Brahma, Devas and the rishis, Narayana, the Lord of the worlds, spoke to Rudra — 'Whoever understands you understands me. Your followers are mine. **There is no difference between you and me, let there not be second thoughts on this.**"

He then bestows upon Shiva the appellation "Shreekantha" since Rudra's Kantha was held by Narayana's auspicious hands. He further names the mark which the Shula made on his chest as Shrivatsa.

> adyaprabhR^iti shrIvatsaH **shUlA~Nko** me bhavatvayam.
> mama pANya~NkitashchApi **shrIkaNThastvaM** bhaviShyasi.. 12-352-68

> "From today let your Shula's mark on my chest be called Shrivatsa, and my hand's mark on your throat give you the name Shreekantha."

Thus, rendering Lord Shiva's Trishula effectless, Narayana, the son of Dharmadeva, accompanied in Badarikashrama by Nara, Krsna and Hari, bestowed boon of a new appellation, and unparalleled friendship (Atulam Sakhyam, 12-352-69) upon Shreekantha.

User @Saurav Dey pointed out that no destruction happens to Rudra's Shula, as also the fact that the Shula is not mentioned as three-pronged.

I would like to mention that the verb Vidhvams, while commonly meaning destruction, or reducing to pieces, also [means, "to injure or hurt" according to Monier Williams' Sanskrit dictionary](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=vidhvaMsa&direct=au&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3).

Also, when referring to Lord Shiva's weapon, he is invariably called Shulapani, Shuli and so on, and it is understood that the Shula of Shiva is a three-pronged lance. Hence the mention of only Shula in the Shanti Parva as opposed to Trishula in the Sahasranama verse can be equated as a synonymous reference.

Comment: Very nice answer +1 and interesting new angle of shiva throat blue because of Vishnu and Vishnu’s chest with Shiva’s hand instead of I think Bhrigu’s foot. Is this Narayana Rishi or Bhagwan Vishnu in Daksha Sacrifice?

Comment: @Archit It is Narayana Rishi.

Answer (score 0):

Sanskrit is a very tricky and ancient language it can mean different to different people like if some one sends a text 1 4 3 to you. It can mean I love you but it can also mean I hate you. Like this only, a sanskrit phase can mean different to different people.

Further lord shiva and lord vishnu have so many names in common because they are one only like Guha, Sudarshana, sanatana, Garuda, Nandi, mahadeva, hari, Keshava,  vishnu, shiva, eka(the only one), bara pradah(giver of boons), vidhvamsee(destroyer), Vijaya(winner), shreekant(kant has 2 meaning one is throat and other is husband so lord Ram is called sitakant and shree can mean maa lakshy, wealth, glorious, maa durga, etc)., khandaparshu, seesha, ananta, anirudha, vishnu, etc.

Now let me translate the same sentence for you but differently so that it matches the puzzle pieces.

> shivatrishoolavidhvamsee shreekanThaikavarapradah |
> narahkrushNo haridharmanandano dharmajeevanah || 52 ||

> *He is Lord Shiva (the most auspicious and pure one), he is the Trishoola ("**Vijaya**" the name of Shiva's trishoola ) [Unbeatable], he is the destroyer (of everything during pralaya as rudra). He is the husband (kant) of shree(Lakshmi) [shree+kant] or the one with a glorious neck(rudra), he is the only one( **ika or eka**), he is the giver of the boons(varapradah).
> He is nara( leader of all the man), he is krishna( black in colour). He is hari(the liberator of souls), he is the son of Dharma(darma+Nandana) [As lord Vishnu's avatar Nara, Narayana, Hari and Krishna were the sons of Dharma]. He is Dharma (righteousness) and he is the life itself(jeevanah).*

I hope this answers your question. I know this may trouble you a bit as our translations dont match but it is what it is because lord Vishnu never ever even tried to destroy lord Shiva's trishoola.

Edit.:
User @surya pointed out that the verse of shanti parva where rudra and narayan fought during daksha yagya. The same fight is also mentioned in shiva maha Purana during the war between vasukhi and Garuda but a different version Where shiva is called sitikant (the one with a mark on his throat) and vishnu is called shrivatsa (the one with a mark on his chest) due to the effect of trishoola lord vishnu became blue in colour and lord shiva healed [him.](https://www.eternalhindutva.com/2019/02/the-fight-of-lord-shiva-and-lord-vishnu.html?m=1)..

Now coming back to the topic we all know that it was Veerabhadra (one of the Rudras) who fought narayana in daksha yagya. And as for shoola it means spike countable noun. A spike is a long piece of metal with a sharp point. Even in the translation of shanti parva it is transtated as a dart(a pointed weapon) or a lance(a spear). Yes lord shiva is called shoolpani which literally translated to lord shiva with a spear in his hand...[translation of this name according to iskon.](https://names.iskcondesiretree.com/shulapani/) and he is called trishoolin (the one who holds trident). Lord shiva has an arsenal of weapons he is also called chakradhari, dhanushdhari, vajradhari, gadadhari, etc.

As for vidhvamsaa anyone who knows proper sanskrit or even proper hindi also knows that it's an extreme word use for destruction, annihilation, extermination, etc it can't mean hurt thought the link was provided because hurt is a light word for hurt word like ghat, aghart, etc can be used. [U can see the shabdakosh or dictionary](https://www.shabdkosh.com/search-dictionary?e=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8&lc=hi&sl=hi&tl=en) . Even in question it is asked about destruction. So **trishoola (trident which has 3 tips) and shoola (spear which only has one tip) cannot be referred to be one and same** like **giving name to someone cannot be called as a boon** because if it is than I myself have given so many boons to so many people and friends.

According to Mahabharata Markandeya-Samasya Parva [Fight between Skanda and Shakra](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/mahabharata_markandeyasamasya_parva.htm) and Skanda Purana [Fight between skanda and tarkasur](https://archive.org/stream/skanda-puran-part-9-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/Skanda%20Puran%20Part%209%20-%20Ancient%20Indian%20Tradition%20And%20Mythology_djvu.txt).

> *To his right Devas and Maruts, the fighters in diverse ways, went along with Vasus and accompanied by Rudras. Accompanied by Mṛtyu and surrounded on all sides by terrible Ailments in hundreds infuriated Yama went on his leftside. Behind Yama went the terrible **white trident of Rudra named Vijaya**. It had three spikes and had been made by Rudra himself. Behind him went Lord Varuṇa, the lord of waters, with a terrible noose. He was surrounded by hundreds of different kinds of aquatic animals. **Rudra’s sharp-edged spear went behind Vijaya surrounded by the excellent weapons** beginning with maces, iron clubs, Śaktis etc.*

So I am sticking to my original version only but still we live in a democracy so it's fine for people to have different opinions so it's ok. Anyways we both did our best which matters the most...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118997/discussion-on-answer-by-saurav-dey-when-did-vishnu-destroy-trident-of-shiva).

Comment: Chanda, Visargah, Vyakaran, alankar, bhav learn it yourself of sanskrit it's useful. 1st don't get confuse in it @ $|_|π¥@... otherwise 2 mk it undrstnd 2 ya is totally hopeless. Per se. Prd.

Comment: I suggest that 2 u n.c. ..